# jQuery show/hide specific news - depending on click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Okay, this is kind of confusing to explain. I basically have a custom basic news system written in PHP. On displaying the news I have used jQuery to "click to display full news article"

Here's a preview of my site, you may understand more with a picture:

[image]

Basically, full news articles are echo'd inside a 
which means when the "View full article" is clicked, it opens them all.

Thank-you in advance if anyone manages to resolve this issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#show").click(function () {
            $(".news").show("slow");
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly makes a problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I have no real error, but more a bug. For example, when I click "View Full Article" it make all the news open.

Comment: Please post some of your code. No one can tell what's wrong with your code until you show it.

Comment: That is basically it. Like I said, it's hard to explain. When "View full news" is click, it will display every <div class="news"></div> meaning that all of my news will be displayed.

Comment: Please post your HTML markup too. It appears that `$('.news')` matches every new container. You need to use more specific selector.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to show a specific article instead of showing all of them. There are multiple ways to do this and mostly depends on how you structure your HTML. But I imagine you have something similar to this:

```
...
<div class="article">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p class="summary">Short Summary of the article</p>
  <p class="news" style="display:none;">FULL ARTICLE</p>  
  <a class="reveal-btn" href="#">Click to reveal full article</a>
</div>

<div class="article">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <p class="summary">Short Summary of the article</p>
  <p class="news" style="display:none;">FULL ARTICLE</p>  
  <a class="reveal-btn" href="#">Click to reveal full article</a>
</div>
...
```

Something like this in jquery should handle per article toggle view:

```
$('.article .reveal-btn').click(function(e){
  $('.summary', $(this).parent()).toggle();
  $('.news', $(this).parent()).slideToggle();
});
```

Something like this should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, you've explained what my problem is! I'll give this a try now :-)

Comment: This has worked, however how could you create a similar code for the close/opposite of what this does? Also, is it possible to add some effects like slide?

Comment: Yes. Use `.slideDown` and `.slideUp` instead of `.show` and `.hide` for animating. Not sure what do you mean by the first question. If you meant a toggle instead of just show, you can use `toggle` instead of `.hide`. I think there's also `.slideToggle` to get the animation effect. Just updated the code to reflect toggle instead of hide/show.

Comment: @mkhatib Can we also customize timings for slideUp and slideDown?

Comment: Yes. They both take a `duration` parameter. Check out the docs http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/. `.slideUp(1000)` this for example will take a second to hide the element.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after the `.toggle()` jQuery function?

e.g.

```
$('#btn-reveal-articles').click(function() {
    $('#article-div').toggle();
});
```

It's hard to determine what you're after without any code to show or a clear definition of the problem.

---

### Edit:

I've whipped up an example for you on jsFiddle here is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/tU8a7/
http://jsfiddle.net/tU8a7/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="news">
    <div class="article">
        <a href="#" class="btn-view">View article</a>
        <div class="content">
            My content for the first article
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="article">
        <a href="#" class="btn-view">View article</a>
        <div class="content">
            My content for the second article
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.article .content { display: none; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.btn-view').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.article').find('.content').toggle();
});
```

There are a whole bunch of toggle options such as `.toggle()`, `.slideToggle()` and `.fadeToggle()`. Each have a parameter option for speed as well so you could set `.toggle(1000)` and it would pad out the animation for one second.

Comment: To be fair, I'm fairly new to jQuery and PHP. Say I have several news articles all inside <div class="news"></div> How would I make it so only the one the user wants to appear, appears?  Instead of every class="news" being displayed?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include an example on jsFiddle for you, hope it helps

Comment: Thank-you ever so much! I've adjusted yours and some of the answers and have managed to fix it. Thank-you for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(".news")` is a class selector, so it will select **all** elements with that class. You will need to come up with a unique identifier for each "article" if you want them shown individually; for instance:

```
<a class="news-toggle" href="#article-1">Show</a>
<div id="article-1" class="news">

</div>
```

and

```
$(function(){

    $('a.news-toggle').on('click', function(e){
        var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
        $(toShow).show(); // or use slideToggle() to use same "button" to hide/show
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For solve a problem like this I append parent id as suffix of child's class or id

```
<div id="article-1">
  <div id="excerpt-1>blah blah ..</div>
  <span id="readmore-1" class="read-more">read full article</span>
  <div id="full-article-1">
    blah blah ...
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case parent id is **1** and then get

```
$('.read-more').on('click', function(){
  var id = this.id.split('-')[1];
  $('#full-article-'+id).show('slow');
});
```